# Finding actual (field) link lengths in network using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have three layers of data: streets, intersections and start/end of links.

How can I get the actual (field) link lengths of every link in the network?

Here link is defined as the street stretch between every node pair.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split your streets into segments using your startpionts, endpoints, and intersections using the [Split Line at Point Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-point.htm).
2. If you are using shapefiles follow [this help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) to calculate the length of your line segments.
   If you're using feature classes the length is calculated automatically.